# Calculating percentage between two subqueries mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the percentage between two sub queries, I have a solution which to me doesn't seem very elegant at all:

```
SET @tot := (select count(*) FROM shipment WHERE created < date_format(date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), interval 1 day), '%Y%m%d000000') AND created >= date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y%m%d000000'))

SELECT @tot AS Total, ((select count(*) from shipment where created < date_format(date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), interval 1 day), '%Y%m%d000000') AND created >= date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y%m%d000000') AND state = 'despatched')  / @tot) * 100 AS Percentage
```

While this works at command line, it fails miserably in a bespoke platform i'm trying to create a report for, i'm wondering if there is a way to simplify this without the usage of a set variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason you couldn't do it simply as a SELECT from a nested subquery. (Untested in MySQL, but works in SQL Server with the proper date functions.)

```
select total, dispatched / total * 100 as percentage from
(
  select count(*) as Total, 
    sum(case when state = 'despatched' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as dispatched
  from 
    shipment
  where 
    created >= date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y%m%d000000') 
  and 
    created < date_format(date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), interval 1 day), '%Y%m%d000000')
) calcs
```